# Does any official website annunciate tuition credits for certain schools offering the equivalent of university courses (Advanced Placement)?

Tags: discussion

I don't grok how [Does any official website annunciate tuition credits for certain schools offering the equivalent of university courses (Advanced Placement)?](https://money.stackexchange.com/q/117211/40527) is "seeking product or service recommendations? I just want an official government source or legal authority for the book's posit.

Answer (score 3):

When members vote to close a question as off-topic, they are offered a menu -

[image]

Now, if off-topic, your question would either be choice 2, or Other, requiring a filled in explanation.

I'll admit, strictly speaking, one an argue 2 doesn't apply. You are asking for something a bit different from a product or service. But, you are wanting a reference, which is different from asking a question 'about' something. In effect, a 'good' (for you) answer would be link-only, after all, there's no need to give you anything but a link. But link-only answers are frowned upon, and would only prompt member to close as such.

The choice of reason for closure should probably be edited, and we'd take that under advisement.